# Using Python loop to compile single graph

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, boxplot

I'm attempting to compile 12 boxplots on a single set of axes using a loop. However, when I run the code as show below, I end up with 12 different figures. Can anyone provide input on how to make sure they all stay on one figure?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mons =['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

for i in range(len(mons)):
   data = np.genfromtxt('Z:/Dan/SnowStatData/Errors/'+mons[i]+'ErrorStats.txt',skip_header=4)
   lat  = data[:,1]
   lon  = data[:,2]
   corr = data[:,3]
   corp = data[:,4]
   RMSE = data[:,5]
   MAE  = data[:,6]
   SDE  = data[:,7]

   sigcorrs = []
   clat = []
   clon = []

   for j in range(len(lat)):
       if corp[j] < 0.05:
           sigcorrs = np.append(sigcorrs,corr[j])
           clat = np.append(clat,lat[j])
           clon = np.append(clon,lon[j])
       else:
           continue

   plt.boxplot(sigcorrs,positions=[i])
   plt.show()
```

Comment: `sigcorrs = np.append(sigcorrs,corr[j])`. Why are you assigning the results of append to a variable?

Comment: @MorganThrapp why would he not?

Comment: @hitzg Because it doesn't return anything? And could easily be rewritting `sigcorrs` with a function pointer.

Comment: @MorganThrapp We're speaking about [numpy's append function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html), which does return something. I believe you mean `list.append`.

Comment: @hitzg My bad. I haven't used numpy a ton, and when I was reading the docs I missed that part.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to create the figure before you start looping:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
```

Now, in the loop don't use `plt.boxplot` which might create a new figure, but call the function directly from the axes object:

```
ax.boxplot(sigcorrs,positions=[i])
```

And then call `plt.show()` after the loop

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling plt.show() every time through the loop, so it's drawing the figure every time. Try putting it after the loop.

Comment: This just shows the last of the 12 figures made. Each is still end up on its own individual figure.